# permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION (kotlin)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, google-maps, android-fragment

soy nuevo en el mundo de desarrollo en Android y tengo un problema al momento de realizar el código para los permisos de localización.
El proyecto es simple tengo un botón llamado ubicación que esta dentro del MainActivity, este al pulsarlo me dirige a un fragment donde se presenta el Mapa, pero al momento de querer realizar la localización me sale **"my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"**

este el código del MainActivity

```
package com.eleczero.mapsapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        botton()
    }

    private fun botton(){
        val buttonOpen: Button = findViewById(R.id.btn_ubicacion)
        buttonOpen.setOnClickListener {
            val myFragment = MapsFragment()
            val fragment: Fragment? =

                supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(MapsFragment::class.java.simpleName)

            if(fragment !is MapsFragment){
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.continer_fragment,myFragment,MapsFragment::class.java.simpleName)
                    .commit()
            }
            buttonOpen.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
}
```

Este el código del MapsFragment

```
package com.eleczero.mapsapp

import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.location.Location
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment


class MapsFragment : Fragment(),OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener {//, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener

    private lateinit var map: GoogleMap

    companion object{
        const val REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION = 0
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        createFracment()

    }

    private fun createFracment(){
        val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)

    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
        map = googleMap
        map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this)
        isLocationPermissionGrandet()
        //enableLocation()
    }

    private fun isLocationPermissionGrandet() = {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission
                .ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Log.i("Permisos", "Se tienen los permisos!")
        }else{

        }
    }
/*
    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    private fun enableLocation(){
        if (!::map.isInitialized) return
        if (isLocationPermissionGrandet()){
            map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        }
    }
*/
    override fun onMyLocationButtonClick(): Boolean {
        return false
    }

}
```

Intente realizar dos funciones una que realice la parte del permiso **(isLocationPermissionGrandet())** y la otra funcion que habilita mi localización **enableLocation()** pero en ambos casos me sale otro error **Type mismatch: inferred type is MapsFragment but Context was expected**, este error me señala en el `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)`
Me ayudarian con sus comentarios o otras perspectivas de como solucionarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La causa del error :

> Type mismatch: inferred type is MapsFragment but Context was expected

Se debe a que haces uso de `this` como contexto pero esto no es correcto, en este caso deberìas enviar el contexto a tu funciòn definiendola de esta forma:

```
  private fun isLocationPermissionGrandet(context : Context) = {
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission
                .ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Log.i("Permisos", "Se tienen los permisos!")
        }else{

        }
    }
```

Al llamar la funciòn, usa como contexto la Activity que contiene el `Fragment` por medio de `activity` :

```
isLocationPermissionGrandet(activity)
```

Comment: Elenasys muchas gracias por la ayuda es no sabia, pero al momento de colocar `isLocationPermissionGrandet(activity)` dentro de mi función enableLocation() me da error, sale que  Type mismatch: inferred type is FragmentActivity? but Context was expected. es algun problema al momento de llamar la funcion dentro del fragment o es que las funciones para permisos se deben de tener una estructura diferente dentro del fragment? y si estoy un poco lento es que soy nuevo en este mundo android!!

Answer (score 0):

Bueno la solución que se logro dar es colocando requireActivity() al momento de pedir los permisos.
El código lo dejo aquí para que lo vean en el caso que alguien tenga un problema similar.
'''
class MapsFragment : Fragment(),OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationButtonClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMyLocationClickListener {

```
private lateinit var map: GoogleMap

companion object{
    const val REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION = 0
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_maps, container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    createFracment()

}

private fun createFracment(){
    val mapFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map) as SupportMapFragment
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this)
}


override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    map = googleMap
    map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(this)
    enableLocation()
}


private fun enableLocation(){ 
    if (!::map.isInitialized) return
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            requireActivity(),Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        map.isMyLocationEnabled = true
    }else{
        requestPermission()
    }
}

private fun requestPermission() {
    if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(requireActivity(),Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){
        Toast.makeText(this.requireActivity(),"ve a ajustes y acepta los permisos",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.requireActivity(), arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
            REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION
        )
    }
}

override fun onMyLocationButtonClick(): Boolean {
    return false
}

override fun onMyLocationClick(p0: Location) {
    Toast.makeText(this.requireContext(),"Estas en ${p0.latitude},${p0.longitude}",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

}
```

'''